# Silverlight: Populate Nested Datagrid when the parent datagrid row is selected

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, asynchronous

I am having problem loading data into Nested datagrid. When the user clicks on a row in parent datagrid, The id is retrieved and based on that the nested datagrid is loaded.

In the rowDetailsVisibilityChanged event.

```
        DataGrid nestedDataGrid = e.DetailsElement as DataGrid;

        SampleObj data= e.Row.DataContext as SampleObj ;

        var client = new MyService.SampleServiceClient();
        client.GetReportArchiveDataCompleted += GetSampleDataCompleted;
        client.GetSampleDataAsync(data);
```

How can I add this line in Asyn completed event as I am not able to get the nested Datagrid in completed event.

IEnumerable dataList= e.Result;
nestedDataGrid.ItemSource = dataList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an anonymous function instead....

```
client.GetReportArchiveDataCompleted += 
  delegate(object sender1, GetReportArchiveDataCompletedArgs e1) {
    nestedDataGrid.ItemSource=(IEnumerable)e1.Result;
  };
```

Obviously change the delegate to the correct signature (same as your GetSampleDataCompleted.